# Adding Day greeting into app on HomeFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app for my college. So i want to add Day wishes (Good Morning, Good Afternoon, Good Evening, Good Night) in HomeFragment.

I have added Day wishes as in Toast Form. Instead of toast i want wishes on my HomeFragment.

```html
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I want to add as text not in toast.

Comment: In your fragment's layout, create a `TextView`, inflate it into MyFragment.java, and then `setText()` Do you want anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google for data binding viewmodel variable getter greeting, access from xml. you will learn a lot, don't do the simple setText(), also use kotlin, not java

read here for more info, there's an example with TextView, what you need: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html